# whats the difference between the following css selectors

Tags: css

```
a[attribute~=val]{
}


a[attribute|=val]{
}


a[attribute*=val]{
}
```

usually i use the last one.. but whats the difference between all of them

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just [look at the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)?

Comment: i did read them.. but there is an overlap in teh usage of them. I can just stick to this a[attribute*=val] instead of using this a[attribute~=val] for example

Comment: Yes, you could, but it just depends how specific you want to be. `[attribute*=val]` will match "somethingval" but `[attribute~=val]` won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attribute Contains Word Selector `~=` will find a word separated by spaces. It will for example find `"Jon"` in `"Jon Peters"` but not in `"Jonathan Peters"`.

The Attribute Contains Prefix Selector `|=` will find a prefix separated with a dash. It will for example find `"en"` in `"en-GB"` but not in `"english"` or `"kal-en"`.

The Attribute Contains Selector `*=` will find text anywhere inside the attribute value.

Comment: the first one is a very weird one. i dont know why i need it , if i can only use the last one: a[attribute*='Jon '] instead of a[attribute~='Jon']

Comment: @BlackFire27: It's useful when you want to match whole words, and not find partial words, e.g. not styling an animal item as a fish because you find `"cod"` in `"crocodile"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[attribute~=val]
```

Matches an `a` element with an `attribute` attribute whose value contains the word "val", delimited by spaces.

```
a[attribute|=val]
```

Matches an `a` element with an `attribute` attribute whose value is exactly "val", or begins with "val-".

```
a[attribute*=val]
```

Matches an `a` element with an `attribute` attribute whose value contains the string "val".

---

You could have found that yourself very easily by [reading the CSS selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: so whats the diffrence between a[attribute|=val] and a[attribute^=val] and about the first syntax does space have to be a delimiter of val

Comment: @BlackFire27 - `[attribute^=val]` matches if the value *starts with* "val". `[attribute|=val]` matches if the value *is* "val" or starts with "val-" (notice the hyphen character). For the first one, the value can be exactly "val", or contain the word "val". But again, read the spec. It explains this all well.